# Deal with in Net 6's nullable and Entity Framework entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Using Net 6 and Entity Framework I have the following entity:

```
public class Address {

  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public String CountryCode { get; set; }  
  public String Locality { get; set; }
  public Point Location { get; set; }

  public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();  

}
```

With `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in project definition I am getting the warnings:

```
Non-nullable property '...' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.
```

In Address properties:

```
CountryCode, Locality, Location and Country.
```

I see a few options to deal with this:

```
public String? CountryCode { get; set; } 

public String CountryCode { get; set; } = null!;
```

I could also add a constructor but not all properties (for example, navigation properties) can be in the constructor.

What would be an approach to this issue?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) show some possibilities. But I agree, this isn't the graal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came across same thing few days back and actually nullable reference type is there in .net 5 too but manually we have to add that into .csproj and with .net 6 it is there by default.

I took following approach.

If I know that my property is non-nullable and when migration generate it should have nullable false then I put this way.

```
public string CountryCode { get; set;} = null!; // This indicate that this property will have value eventually. so no warning generate during compilation.
```

When I know property can contain null and also nullable = true in db or migration then

```
public string? CountryCode {get;set;}
```

Comment: I think using "`public string? CountryCode {get;set;}` or `public string CountryCode { get; set;} = null!;` is irrelevant when using EF migrations. What is in the entity configuration is what is applied. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is relevant. `string` results in non-nullable field (REQUIRED) while `string?` allows null value. At least for SQLite and SQL Server.

Comment: Partially correct. Means if you explicitly provide setting then it is fine but if you just add builder.Property(x=>x.Countrycode). At this time nullable reference type play its role generate migration like nullable column or non-nullable column.

Comment: @dotnetstep Ok, I am setting `Required`to `true` or `false` in my entities Fluent Configuration so it seems making the properties as nullable or not is overridden  by the entity's fluent configuration.

Comment: I've wondered about this a bit. Using null! isn't great. It's fine for records retrieved from the database, but if you're constructing a record yourself then a string property would be null unless you explicitly set it to something. You could then try to access that property in your code and visual studio would not warn you of the risk. It would be better to use string.empty perhaps, but this would be wasteful if you were retrieving a lot of records with such fields. On the other hand, if I'm retrieving a lot of records I'm likely to be projecting them rather than fetching raw entities

Answer (score 15):

Since .NET 7, you can use [Required property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties) instead:

```cs
public required Product Product { get; set; } // Add required keyword
```

---

**Previous answer**

Personally, I just put this line on the top of all my model files (POCO/JSON models, DbContext etc):

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

Just put that line on top of the file, no need to `restore` it.

There is another ["official" solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) but it's horrible:

```
public Product Product { get; set; } = null!;
```

The doc did list my solution as valid as well anyway but you don't need to repeat it for each property.

A tip on how to create that line if you use VS:

[image]

You get something like this:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    public TestContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

Delete the last line and cut the first line to the top of the file.